# How do you do a where clause with a select statement as a value

Tags: sql, where-clause

I'm trying to get the total amount from the next month's record.

```
SELECT TOP (1000) 
    [DEMAND_POINT_ID],
    [DPM_XREF_ID],
    [UTIL_TYPE],
    [ACCOUNT_ID],
    [REV_YR_MNTH],
    [TOTAL_AMOUNT],
    (SELECT CAST(LEFT((SELECT CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(month, 1, LEFT(REV_YR_MNTH, 4) + '-' + RIGHT(REV_YR_MNTH, 2) + '-' + '01'), 112)), 6) AS int)) AS nextmonth,
    (SELECT de2.[TOTAL_AMOUNT]
     FROM [DEQEnergyUsage].[dbo].[DST_ENERGY_USAGE_AGGR] de2
     WHERE de2.ACCOUNT_ID = de.ACCOUNT_ID 
       AND de2.REV_YR_MNTH = (SELECT CAST(LEFT((SELECT CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(month, 1, LEFT(REV_YR_MNTH, 4) + '-' + RIGHT(REV_YR_MNTH, 2) + '-' + '01'), 112)), 6) AS int))) AS nextamount
FROM 
    [DEQEnergyUsage].[dbo].[DST_ENERGY_USAGE_AGGR] de
WHERE
    ACCOUNT_ID =1 
ORDER BY 
    ACCOUNT_ID, de.REV_YR_MNTH
```

The value `nextmonth` creates the next month's `rev_yr_mnth` correctly however when I try to use this created value in the where clause it brings back nothing in the `nextamount` field.

[image]

It's like it does not recognize the created value as a true value. What do I need to do to have the where clause recognize the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CTE you can add condition on `nextmonth`.

```
With CTE As (
SELECT TOP (1000) 
    [DEMAND_POINT_ID],
    [DPM_XREF_ID],
    [UTIL_TYPE],
    [ACCOUNT_ID],
    [REV_YR_MNTH],
    [TOTAL_AMOUNT],
    (SELECT CAST(LEFT((SELECT CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(month, 1, LEFT(REV_YR_MNTH, 4) + '-' + RIGHT(REV_YR_MNTH, 2) + '-' + '01'), 112)), 6) AS int)) AS nextmonth,
    (SELECT de2.[TOTAL_AMOUNT]
     FROM [DEQEnergyUsage].[dbo].[DST_ENERGY_USAGE_AGGR] de2
     WHERE de2.ACCOUNT_ID = de.ACCOUNT_ID 
       AND de2.REV_YR_MNTH = (SELECT CAST(LEFT((SELECT CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(month, 1, LEFT(REV_YR_MNTH, 4) + '-' + RIGHT(REV_YR_MNTH, 2) + '-' + '01'), 112)), 6) AS int))) AS nextamount
FROM 
    [DEQEnergyUsage].[dbo].[DST_ENERGY_USAGE_AGGR] de
WHERE
    ACCOUNT_ID =1 
ORDER BY 
    ACCOUNT_ID, de.REV_YR_MNTH
)
select * from CTE
-- Where nextmonth condition
```

Comment: I tried that with `where nextmonth = (SELECT CAST(LEFT((SELECT CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(month, 1, LEFT(REV_YR_MNTH, 4) + '-' + RIGHT(REV_YR_MNTH, 2) + '-' + '01'), 112)), 6) AS int))` and it still comes up blank and `rev_yr_mnth = nextmonth` brings up nothing

Comment: I was able to resolve my issue by including `UTIL_TYPE = 'G'` to each `WHERE` clause